# Change Windows 8 App Background in real time (C#/XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, background, switch-statement, toggle

I'm doing a Windows 8 application (METRO UI / XAML / C#) and I have a Toggle Switch in the settings bar. I want this switch to select between a "light" and a "dark" theme, in real time.
I already made the themes on my StandardStyles.xaml:

```
<!-- LIGHT THEME -->

<Style x:Key="LightTheme" TargetType="Panel">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="#cdeae5" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#c0dabd" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ChildrenTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- DARK THEME -->

<Style x:Key="DarkTheme" TargetType="Panel">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="#fea569" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#f63f3b" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ChildrenTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How do I select them in real time with the toggle switch?
I think it'd be something like this:

```
private void ThemeSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ThemeSwitch.IsOn)
        {
            // LIGHT THEME
            // TEXT SHOWING "Light Theme"
        }
        else
        {
            // DARK THEME
            // TEXT SHOWING "Dark Theme"
        }

    }
```

But that's the furthest I can go.

Thanks in advance. This is the first time I'm programming in C# and XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I can't change the theme in real time:

> **Note**  The theme is applied when the app is started. You can't change themes while the app is running.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986965.aspx

Well, that sucks.

Answer (score 0):

use below c# code

```
grdMain.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 123, 183, 42));
```

Comment: That will change the background color, but how does this answer the question about themes?